# Trying to make a stack of strings. Getting missing type specifier error

Tags: c++

So I've tried adding an int to where the error is coming from, but that just adds a ton of new errors. I've googled around for a bit, but I haven't found anything that helps me, or maybe I just don't understand a lot of whats being said.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Define the stack class, set default stack size to 7
//use a template to define type at later point

template<class T,int size=7>
class stack
{
private: T data[size];
int stack_ptr;
public:
stack(void);
void push(T x);
T pop();
T top();
};

//constructor function to initialize stack and data
template<class T, int size>
stack<T, size>::stack(void)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<size;i++) data[i]=0;
stack_ptr=0;
}

//Push data onto stack
template<class T,int size>
void stack<T, size>::push(T x)
{
if(stack_ptr>=size)
  {

    cout<<"cannot push data: stack full"<<endl;
    return;
  }
data[stack_ptr++]=x;
cout<<"Pushed\t" << x << "\tonto the stack"<<endl;
return;
}

//Pop data from stack
template<class T, int size>
stack<T, size>::pop()
{
using namespace std;
if(stack_ptr<=0)
  {

    cout<<"cannot pop data: stack empty"<<endl;
    return data[0];
  }
cout<<"popped\t"<< data[--stack_ptr]<< "\tfrom stack"<<endl;
return data[stack_ptr];
}


int main()
{

//declaring stack of strings and using default size
stack<string> c;
string w;
string name1 = "Rich";
string name2 = "Debbie";
string name3 = "Robin";
string name4 = "Dustin";
string name5 = "Philip";
string name6 = "Jane";
string name7 = "Joseph";
c.push(name1);
c.push(name2);
c.push(name3);
c.push(name4);
c.push(name5);
c.push(name6);
c.push(name7);

//pick up the stack value
w=c.pop();
string & i = c.top( );
string next_top = c.top();

cout << "The top person the stack is " << next_top << "."<< endl;

return 0;
}
```

And here is my error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: A-2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  A-2.cpp
1>h:\pf3\a-2\a-2\a-2.cpp(55): error C4430: missing type specifier-int assumed.         
Note:    C++ does not support default-int
```

I'm not sure what else I can do, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the line that is causing the error?

Comment: You have no type-specifier for your pop() member. wtb a `T`

Comment: `std::stack<string>`

Comment: Where am I supposed to put that? I tried replacing stack<string> c; with that in main but it didn't go over so well.

Comment: That was supposed to be used instead of using your stack class. I assume you need to create your own stack class however for some assignment.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a return type on the implementation of `pop`. Looks like you intended for the return type to be `T` from the declaration:

```
template<class T, int size>
T stack<T, size>::pop()
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I made the change that you are showing, but I just got a bunch of new errors. I'm trying to post them, but I'm new to this forum and haven't quite figured it out yet.

Comment: @Dorden Post a new question with the new error. Try to debug them first though and narrow it down. It helps if you can pinpoint the lines that are causing you problems. That's generally how this works. However, Andreas Florath has now posted an answer with some more fixes. They should help.

Comment: @Dorden To be clear, you *can* edit your post, but you should usually only do that if it's still going to be the same question. You have new errors so they deserve a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and fix this with what you guys gave me before making a new question

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems:

1. (As sftrabbit showed): Missing T as return type spec for pop.
2. `string & i = c.top( );`is not valid: Reference to temporary
3. `for(i=0;i<size;i++) data[i]=0` does not work for other than int-types as `T`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out for me. I'll see if I can get it to work from here.